# Animate div block when Angular View loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9c9jfnn/) I have a block sliding in from the left after two seconds.

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('testApp', [])
        .controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
            $scope.title = "Hello";

            $scope.show = false;

            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.show = true;
            }, 2000);
        });

})(angular);
```

I would like to have the block sliding in when the view is rendered and can be seen by the user.

There is already a style that  can be applied to get the block sliding in.

```
.left-inner-nav {
    position:absolute; 
      top:0; 
      /*left:75px;*/
      left: -150px;
      width: 150px; 
      bottom: 0; 
      background:#2792D9;
    -webkit-transition: left 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 2s ease;
    -ms-transition: left 2s ease;
    -o-transition: left 2s ease;
    transition: left 2s ease;
}

.left-inner-nav-animate {
    left: 0;
}
```

I'm just stuck as to how to do this on view load.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [`ngAnimate`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ngAnimate) is for.

ngAnimate adds 4 classes, for different ngView states.

```
<style>
.slide.ng-enter { }        /* starting animations for enter */
.slide.ng-enter.ng-enter-active { } /* terminal animations for enter */
.slide.ng-leave { }        /* starting animations for leave */
.slide.ng-leave.ng-leave-active { } /* terminal animations for leave */
</style>
```

Download and include a reference to `angular-animate.js`. Then, add ngAnimate as a dependency

```
angular.module('testApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

#### Update

Markup

```
<div ng-view class="left-inner-nav"></div>
```

CSS

```
.left-inner-nav.ng-enter {} /* starting animations for enter */
.left-inner-nav.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {} <style>
```

.slide.ng-enter { }        /* starting animations for enter */
.slide.ng-enter.ng-enter-active { } /* terminal animations for enter */

Comment: Yeah just added `ngAnimate` as dependency. I'm just trying it out

Comment: Could you maybe show how this would work in my scenario, it is still a little confusing

Comment: I see the problem here - I'm not using an ngView directive, will have to make it work for ui-router

Comment: So, what do you want to animate ? :)

Comment: I'm animating a `ui-view`, I got this animation to work with `ng-show`.